# Give a stroke a texture fill of an image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I have create multiple circles and I want to have the stroke of these circles to have a fill of a gold texture image I have download. I have tried to using the clipping mask but that only create a fill of the gold texture not the stroke.

Comment: It might be easier to apply 2 fills and offset one inward via the Appearance Panel. Without more information as to the nature of the "gold texture" and what you are trying to achieve exactly, its difficult to say whether this would work well for you or not. It is certainly easier than expanding strokes and masking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your stroke to a shape. Luckily Illustrator has a function that does exactly this: Object > Path > Outline Stroke. Be sure you've got the correct stroke weight before you do this because you won't be able to adjust it afterwards. Then you can use the new shape(s) as a clipping mask.